# How do i get just one result based on two columns in which order of values define unique index

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this situation in my oracle database: I have a table called **CONNECTIONS** that holds two foreign keys to the **OBJECTS** table and the date that the connection was made. The order in which the connection is made is relevant for the system, so the connection

```
OBJ1 | OBJ2 | DATE_CONN_MADE
-----------------------------
1    | 2    | 01/01/2000
```

is different from the connection

```
OBJ1 | OBJ2 | DATE_CONN_MADE
----------------------------
2    | 1    | 01/01/2000
```

My question is: there's a way that i could get the day in which the bidirectional connection was made.

The relevant piece of my schema is

Table OBJECTS:

`ID | NAME`

Table CONNECTIONS

`OBJ1 | OBJ2 | DATE_CONN_MADE`

OBJ1 and OBJ2 are foreign key to OBJECTS.ID

I came up with the query

```
SELECT c.date_conn_made
  FROM CONNECTIONS c
 WHERE    (    c.obj1 = {parameter}
           AND c.obj2 IN (SELECT c.obj1
                            FROM CONNECTIONS
                           WHERE c.obj2 = {parameter}))
       OR (    c.obj2 = {parameter}
           AND c.obj1 IN (SELECT c.obj2
                            FROM CONNECTIONS
                           WHERE c.obj1 = {parameter}));
```

that give me all two dates for the pair of connections, but i wish to get only the greater one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `SELF JOIN` on `CONNECTIONS`? That will give all the available pairs.

```
SELECT c1.date_conn_made, c1.obj1, c1.obj2, 
FROM CONNECTIONS c1
JOIN CONNECTIONS c2 ON c1.date_conn_made =  c2.date_conn_made 
                       AND c1.obj1=c2.obj2 
                       AND c2.obj1=c1.obj2;
```

It assumes that you're interested in bidirectional connection made on the same date. Will it work for you?

If you want the date when bi-directional connection was completed (assuming that each direction can happen on the same date, then:

```
SELECT MAX(c1.date_conn_made), c1.obj1, c1.obj2, 
FROM CONNECTIONS c1
JOIN CONNECTIONS c2 ON c1.obj1=c2.obj2 AND c2.obj1=c1.obj2
GROUP BY c1.obj1, c1.obj2;
```

All the above code is untested.

Comment: Thanks @pm77-1 for your reply, the self join solve my problem. It never occur to me to take that road.  
  
I was indeed searching for the day that the second connection (that one that makes the relationship between objects bi-directional) is made. It actually doesn't matter if they are made in the same day cause the days will be the same, and anyone of them will work for me, i just need to get the greater one if they are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this without a self join, by using aggregation in a clever way.

```
select least(obj1, obj2), greatest(obj1, obj2), max(date_conn_made)
from connections
group by least(obj1, obj2), greatest(obj1, obj2);
```

The use of `least()` and `greatest()` put the two objects in the same order, regardless of the original direction.